# gitlab and its "a default branch does not exist" caused problems

Tags: git, gitlab

I created a repository in gitlab and discovered that my developers can not initiate this repo. (Googling it shows that it seems to be an unresolved bug) with the error message being

```
A default branch (master) does not yet exist
Ask a project Owner to create a default branch
```

So I had a branch new repo and the developer could not upload its code.
So I did the following:

1. I created a default README and the repo got a master branch
2. In my developer PC, we did `git fetch origin master`

So now, master and origin/master was in two different places

I tried `git merger origin/master` but I got
`fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories`

I guess because all the work was in the developer's master and the origin/master was almost empty (except the README)

So I did

1. `git checkout -b newBranch`
2. `git rebase origin/master`

And now I have the whole development over origin/master so I can do

`git push origin newBranch`

and the developer's work is uploaded to the repo

However there are two things that are worrying me:

1. When I do `git log` the newBranch branch is over origin/master but there is no `master` anywhere. When I do it with show all, the master appears below origin/master and the supposedly rebased commits are actually copied. Why master does not appear in git log is unknown to me
2. How I can solve this mess? Ideally I would like the developer to have also a master branch that reflects what it is in the repo. Right now he is working only from `newBranch`

Comment: Nothing in what you described is supposed to have created a local `master` branch. Which command did you expect to do this? Did the developer tried to simply `git checkout master`? You say "there is no `master` anywhere", but the existence of an `origin/master` ref in the local repo hints at a `master` branch existing on the remote repo.

Comment: I think I did not explain my self. The error "there is no master" happened when the repo was just created. The origin/master appeared after I created a Readme and commited in gitlab. And in the local side, the master branch is created when the developer did git init and commited his changes

Answer (score 2):

An *empty* repository, such as the one you created here, never has any branches.

This is not an *error* but it makes the repository useless.  To correct the problem, you must put at least one commit *into the repository*.  The existence of the first ever commit allows you to create as many branch names as you like.  One of those branch names can then be the default branch.  You may choose any name you like *for* the default branch, but in order to *create any branch names*, you must have *at least one commit*.

That's really all there is to it.  This is why "create new repository" operations on many web hosting sites offer to create the first commit for you as well.

(Now that you have an `origin/master` in your local repository, you can `git switch master` to create a local `master` too, if you want.  But there's no reason you *must* have a local `master` branch name.  The point of having a branch name is to help you find commits, and to help you as you add new commits *to* that branch: you create a name if you want to find a specific commit and/or add commits there.)

Comment: The situation is that now locally (in the developer machine) there is the `origin/master` followed by two commits of the `newBranch` branch. Is there any way that he can have a master branch too. (git log doesn't show the master and git log --all strangely show master before origin/master and the commits have not been rebased but **copied**.)

Comment: `origin/master` is not a *branch* name. It's a *remote-tracking name*. It exists in your repository because your Git software saw that the *other* Git repository, over at `origin`, has a branch named `master`. You may create your own `master` if you wish. Rebase works by copying commits, so "not been rebased but copied" does not make sense.

Comment: mmm, I thought rebasing moved commits (strictly speaking copy commits and delete the ones being copied). I guess I was wrong.

Comment: It doesn't delete the originals - it just copies the commits and moves one branch name. If there are more branch names, the other branch names still find the old commits. That's probably what happened here.

Comment: I think gitlab could use current branch from first commit as default branch.

Comment: @EugenKonkov: GitLab *could* do that. Whether they *do* do that, is up to GitLab. Git does not do that by default.